# Mouse Coordinates in Graph Window

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I'm trying to figure out how to find the mouse coordinates when clicking on the graph window a few times.
So far I've tried
`mx ,my = win.mouseX(), win.mouseY()`  and it tells me that the Nonetype is not callable. I've seen other posts involving tkinter, but I am not using that library even though I see that it's easier. Some more example code is as follows:

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin("test", 300, 300)
for i in range(3):
    win.getMouse()
    mx, my = win.mouseX(), win.mouseY()
print(mx,my)
```

I want the above code to have the user click on the window and print the regarding mouse coordinates. Eventually I want to store these coordinates, but I think I can figure that out.

Comment: You're using the Zelle graphics.py library, right? Please tag with "zelle-graphics" if so.

Comment: you should put `print()` inside `for`-loop to display all postions. OR you will have to add them to list - if you want to use them to draw some figure.

Comment: it seems Zelle graphics.py  doesn't have functions `mouseX()`, `mouseY()`. Where did you get from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`win.getMouse()`](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf) returns a Point which you can get coordinates from like this:

```py
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin("test", 300, 300)
for i in range(3):
    point = win.getMouse()
    mx, my = point.getX(), point.getY()
print(mx,my)
```